# Set number of digits after decimal separator

Tags: output-formatting

How can I specify the amount of digits after the decimal separator in output without limiting the total number of digits?

Simple question, but I could not find the answer anywhere. I did find `SetPrecision`. However, that let's me specify the amount of digits in total, but I am looking for a way to specify the number of digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: Probably you want [`SetAccuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAccuracy.html)?  Perhaps also see [(3736)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121), [(55292)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55292/121), [(72454)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72454/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NumberForm[f, {∞, n}]
```

with `n` being the number of digits beyond the decimal separator