# Formatting a list of values and dependent formatting of corresponding errors list

Tags: output-formatting, precision-and-accuracy, conditional

I am making a table of data that I wish to output using `TeXForm`.
Rather than manipulate the values in LaTeX (e.g. using the `siunitx` package), I would like to have the numbers trimmed in MAA before export.

The dataset has the following form:

```
vallist = {697123., 1234.25, 530.25, 67.9101, 1.002679, 0.02570, 0.0000135, 0};

errlist = {1234.4, 210.16, 330.1, 0.0231, 0.0543, 0.000617, 0.0000026, 0.0019}
```

In order to make the final table neat/compact I would like to limit the output size of each value as follows:

1. Values >= 100 presented as 4-significant figure integers (no decimal point); 
   corrsponding error: 2-significant digits followed by zeros
2. 100 > value >0.001: four significant digits; error: 2 significant digits limited to a maximum of 3 decimal places
3. value <0.001: "<0.001" ; error: ""
4. values of 0 or 0. -> "n.d." ; error: ""

So for the above lists the output would be something like:

```
{{697100, 1234, 530, 67.91, 1.003, 0.026, "<0.001", "n.d."}, 
 {2100,   210,  330, 0.023, 0.054, 0.001,   "",      ""}}
```

To format the values I've tried a set of nested `If` statements:

```
If[IntegerPart[#] \[GreaterSlantEqual] 100, IntegerPart[#], 
   If[# == 0, "n.d.", 
    If[Round[#, 0.001] == 0, "<0.001", Round[#, 0.001]]]](*]*)& /@ 
 SetPrecision[vallist, 4]
```

which gives:

> {697123, 1234, 530, 67.91, 1.003, 0.026, "<0.001", "n.d."}

Which is not quite right (i.e. the largest value retains digits below the number of digits specified by `SetPrecision`.

I'm also not yet sure how to approach modifying the corresponding error values.

Can anyone suggest a (more) sensible way to format these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Using inspiration from this [question about significant figures](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72454/permanently-rounding-numbers-values-to-a-given-number-of-significant-figures):

```
sf[x_, n_] := Module[{t}, 
  If[IntegerQ[t = Round[x, 10^(Floor[Log10[x]] - n + 1)]], t, N[t]]]

numform[{v_, e_}] := Which[
  v >= 100,
  {Round[sf[v, 4]], sf[e, 2]},
  v >= 0.001,
  {Round[sf[v, 4], 0.001], Round[sf[e, 2], 0.001]},
  v == 0,
  {"n.d.", ""},
  v < 0.001,
  {"<0.001", ""}
  ]

valerrlist = Transpose[{vallist, errlist}];
numform[#] & /@ valerrlist
```

> {{697100, 1200}, {1234, 210}, {530, 330}, {67.91, 0.023}, {1.003, 0.054}, {0.026, 0.001}, {"<0.001", ""}, {"n.d.", ""}}

Answer (score 0):

The following works for the dataset provided. Transpose the lists:

`valerrlist = Transpose@{vallist, errlist}`

> {{697123., 1234.3}, 
>   {1234.25, 210.16}, {530.25, 330.1}, {67.9101, 
>     0.0231}, {1.00268, 0.0543}, {0.0257, 0.000617}, {0.0000135, 
>     2.6*10^-6}, {0, 0.0019}}

Define a function which looks at each number pair and formats the error values depending on the trimmed value.

```
format[{val_, err_}] := 
 Module[{valout, errout}, 
  valout = Which[IntegerPart[val] \[GreaterSlantEqual] 100, 
    IntegerPart[val], val == 0, "n.d.", Round[val, 0.001] == 0, 
    "<0.001", True, Round[val, 0.001]]; 
  errout = If[NumberQ[valout], 
    Which[IntegerPart[err] \[GreaterSlantEqual] 100, IntegerPart[err],
      err == 0, "", err < 0.0005, "", True, Round[err, 0.001]], ""];

  {valout, errout}
  ]
format[#] & /@ valerrlist
```

> {{697123, 1234}, {1234, 210}, {530, 330},
>
> {67.91, 0.023}, {1.003, 0.054}, {0.026, 0.001},
>
> {"<0.001", ""}, {"n.d.", ""}}

I haven't tested it extensively but it seems to work ok.

```
%//TeXForm
```

\begin{array}{cc}
 697100 & 1200 \\
 1230 & 210 \\
 530 & 330 \\
 67.91 & 0.023 \\
 1.003 & 0.054 \\
 0.026 & 0.001 \\
 \text{$<$0.001} & \text{} \\
 \text{n.d.} & \text{} \\
\end{array}